# Laggy animation

Tags: dart, flutter

Does anyone have experienced laggy transition between screens when using a TabBar, or am I using it wrong ? Basically I am using it as following by building page in other widgets

```
home: DefaultTabController(
    initialIndex: 0,
    length: 5,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: 'HOME'),
            Tab(text: 'SCHEDULE'),
            Tab(text: 'ANALYTICS'),
            Tab(text: 'TEMP'),
            Tab(text: 'SETTINGS'),
          ],
        ),
        title: Text('${widget.title}'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          TheGridView().build(),
          SchedulePage(),
          ChartPage(),
          TempPage(),
          SettingsPage(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Did you check in release or debug mode? Performance in debug mode is not representative. It might also be device-dependent.

Comment: I check this in debug mode actually. It's actually running well on an iPhone 8 but struggle a lot on an iPhone 6

Comment: Check in release mode to be sure. Debug mode has quite different performance characteristics due to JiT (debug) vs AoT compilation (release) and also other reasons.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It looks like perf are better, i'll try tomorrow on iOS :) Thanks !

Comment: I am having this issue and release was better than profile which was better than debug but there is still some frustrating lag that I don't see with the CupertinoTabScaffold. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you share your solution if you got please ?

Comment: @Letitbe (Sorry for the off) If the answer is entirely wrong, vote it down and flag (if it is not even an answer). Do not change the original intent of the OP. Edit an answer only if it would mean the same, only better. If you have a different answer, then post that as your answer.

Answer (score 9):

The `TabBarView` doesn't save the state of the widgets in it. They are rebuilt everytime they reappear on screen. You can check this by adding a `print()` statement in `initState()` for one of the widgets. To fix this you can use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`

```
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SettingsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SettingsPageState createState() => _SettingsPageState();
}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin { //<-- AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; //Set to true

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); //You must add this
    return Container(); //A screen here
  }
}
```

With this small change, the widgets won't rebuild every time they are brought back to the screen

Answer (score 0):

You have not used TabsController maybe it can help you with the performance of tabs.

```
TabController controller;
```

and in initState()

```
controller = new TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
```

Like in here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try your application in release mode:

```
flutter build apk
```

Take the apk and install it in your device (i did through drive)
and check if work better.

In debug mode is normal have a worse experience. 
Debug mode is not just the process of debugging with your cable... is a kind of apk.

I hope this work for you.